# Is there a deliberate crippling of CiviCRM in order to generate income for development?

Tags: activities

The headline is sensationalistic, I know. But on a more rational level, I'm new to the Civi scene but I've dealt with other open source software and have not yet found any that seems to have such a diverse development ecosystem that waves off bugs without trying to fix. Am I missing something on the intent of this? On the surface it looks like "no we won't fix, here are our rates if you want something". Am I wrong?

Here's my example. I have CiviCRM v4.7.29. If I go to Administer, Customize, Activity Types, there are 19 types that are listed, including 3 that I created. All are enabled. When I go to create an Activity for a Contact, I only see 4. So I go to look this issue up and find a similar issue [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/how-to-control-which-activity-types-options-appear-in-dropdown-when-creating-new/20445). Okay, no problem it shows where to go to report this as a bug [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21163). This is where it gets interesting. Look at the Details of this bug. Bug? Yes. Important? Yes. Status? Won't do. Funding source: Needs funding.

This is not some additional obscure functionality that 1 out of 1000 people might want to use, this is pretty much core functionality. Civi is designed for CRM, and Activities **ARE** CRM. Obviously, someone has to pay for development, whether it be volunteer time or paid development time. So why isn't this considered important enough to put on the to-do list?

Not trying to accuse anyone of shenanigans (my headline was to catch a few eyes), I just would like to know how these decisions are made. Thanks and have a great day.

Comment: "When I go to create an Activity for a Contact, I only see 4". Because most of the Activity Types are system generated ones and hence aren't available to be added by a user.

Comment: Seems like you have mainly managed to insult people :-)

Comment: Yes it seems so, I've enjoyed the responses actually. The headline was fun to write :D

Answer (score 2):

Likely because not enough people have marked it as a priority. I've been using CiviCRM for over a decade now and there is a *LOT* of work done on it to fix bugs, add features, etc. There are plenty of bugs that I've alerted to that have gotten fixed. Others just don't have enough people who have an issue with it and therefore funding needs to be chipped in to fix it.

And reading the issue that was reported, it appears that they misunderstood the issue since they were saying that it works as designed. Hence the "won't fix".

Comment: I concur. i just made an Activity Type on WP and then went back in to Edit and had the field to change it from Case only to Contacts and Cases.

Answer (score 2):

Slow down, hombre.

> Coleman Watts added a comment - 15/Sep/17 10:14 AM
>
> > I tested and this is working by design. Editing a reserved activity type will not allow you to change the component. But editing a user-created activity type will.

If you look at the History tab, you can see the issue was then marked resolved at 15/Sep/17 10:14 AM *without changing any other values on the issue*. In Coleman's view, what was reported was not a bug, so there is nothing to fix. *Needs Funding* is a default value, unless a source is specified. *Bug* and *Important* are values set by the *original reporter* — not by a core team member, not by a JIRA manager, and not by a community member.

If Coleman made a mistake, or if you think community members should be allowed to edit issue fields, that is a separate issue entirely.

You claim to be familiar with open source projects, but that does not appear to be the case. According the license CiviCRM is released under, there is no mechanism for the original developers to withdraw it or demand payment for it, but neither can you force them to do anything according to your priorities. By the same token, anyone can [contribute patches](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/core/contributing/). If anything, the core team regularly begs for people to do so.